# How can i add jquery close function in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/JoEXqX)**

As you can see there is a *Show Div* link. If you click the link then my jquery code making this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.click').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   $('.popup').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
   $('.popup').css('display', 'block');
   $(this).parent().next('.openingdiv').toggleClass('height');
   $(this).toggleClass('zindex');

}) 
});
```

So when you click the `Show Div` link then you can see there is a `close` link in the `.openingdiv`. I want to add when the close button is clicked then `.popup` and `.openingdiv` closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this `click` event on your code:

```
$('.closediv a').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.popup').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'linear');
   $('.popup').css('display', 'none');
   $(this).parents('.openingdiv').toggleClass('height');

})
```

If you want `.opening` div close before `.popup` div then you should wait 1s as `.opening` div transition and then execute the code for `.popup`. You can use a `setTimeout`. Try:

```
$('.closediv a').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).parents('.openingdiv').toggleClass('height');
   setTimeout(function(){
     $('.popup').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'linear');
     $('.popup').css('display', 'none');
   }, 1000);
})
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yygVJE)**

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can i ask you something is there when you click close link then `.opening` div close before `.popup` div.

Answer (score 0):

You can add click handler for close button as shown below and there you need to remove `height` class

```
$('.closediv a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.popup').animate({'opacity':'1'}, 300, 'linear');
    $('.popup').css('display', 'none'); 
    $(this).closest('.openingdiv').removeClass('height');
  });
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwaNzo)**

Comment: thanks for your help. Can i ask you something is there a chance of closing before opening a popup div ?

Comment: you mean close previously opened popup div if any and then open new one, is that what you want?

Comment: No, when click close link. Then `.opening` div close before `.popup`.

Comment: May be this is possible and searched for the solution but did not find any. sorry for that.